# node js console code is executed two times

Tags: node.js

I am executing following simple node js code

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello Node JS');
    console.log('printing the message');
}).listen(8080);
```

After executing the command `node sample.js` and

hitting the url on browser `http://localhost:8080/`

I am getting the console log statement twice on the command prompt as `printing the message`

Any Suggestions

**EDIT:**

Interestingly After checking on other browsers i.e. Firefox, IE no favicon.ico request is made on network tab and console message is printed only once.

As I understood, using `express` module is better option to handle requests in a typical web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the Network area of your browser's developer console to find out what requests are being made.  I imagine you will see two:

- `GET /`
- `GET /favicon.ico`

your HTTP server is coded to respond to all requests by printing to console; so if you see two requests, you get two console messages.

Comment: thanks, you are right but how to correct this behaviour ? Since I want to execute my console statement only once at the time of the request.

Comment: your browser is making two requests.  your server says "upon every request regardless of path, print to console".  it is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.  if you want to print a message in some circumstances but not others, you will have to add that logic to your server.